# how to do to treeview-menu always open?

Tags: bootstrap-4, adminlte

I want to my treeview-menu always open, But when user click it will close or open once and does not affect other treeview-menu

like this

[image]

here is my funtion in the adminlte.js:

```
+function ($) {
  'use strict'

  var DataKey = 'lte.tree'

  var Default = {
    animationSpeed: 500,
    accordion     : true,
    followLink    : false,
    trigger       : '.treeview a'
  }

  var Selector = {
    tree        : '.tree',
    treeview    : '.treeview',
    treeviewMenu: '.treeview-menu',
    open        : '.menu-open, .active',
    li          : 'li',
    data        : '[data-widget="tree"]',
    active      : '.active'
  }

  var ClassName = {
    open: 'menu-open',
    tree: 'tree'
  }

  var Event = {
    collapsed: 'collapsed.tree',
    expanded : 'expanded.tree'
  }
```